# Numpy boolean logic (check if element is not something)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

when  I run  `if field[x,y,z] != [-1,-1,-1]:` this error is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dinos\Desktop\CODE\Render\Camera.py", line 63, in controll
    print(self.snap())
  File "C:\Users\dinos\Desktop\CODE\Render\Camera.py", line 59, in snap
    return "".join(self.breakUpArray(self.pBetweenPlane(),self.ep["ab"]))+"\n"+self.getInfo()
  File "C:\Users\dinos\Desktop\CODE\Render\Camera.py", line 42, in pBetweenPlane
    if self.field.field[p2[0],p2[1],p2[2]] != self.field.background:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

"field" is a 4d-np array created with `np.full([100, 100, 100, 3], -1)`. I know the errormessage does give a hint but how would I check `if field[x,y,z] is not [-1,-1,-1]`?

Comment: One way is to check the sum of the array.  If it’s not -3000000 (for example) then one or more values is not -1.  Or check the sum of each axis ... same logic applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.array([-1, -1, -1]) == [-1, -1, -1]` evaluates to `[True, True, True]` as numpy compares them index by index

you'd probably want `if not all(field[x,y,z] == [-1,-1,-1])`

Comment: alternatively, `np.any(field[x,y,z]!=[-1,-1,-1])` is an equivalent operation.